# C# Forms. How to connect send button with checkbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button that sends mail on click but I want it to send mail every time timer tick occurs and I use checkbox to tell the program it's suppose to send every 5 minutes. What should I write in if loop to make it execute what's in timer2_Tick? Else just sends mail once after clicking the button.

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chbRepeat.Checked)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            MailHelper zmienna = new MailHelper();
            zmienna.wyslijMaila(tbAdresat.Text, tbTemat.Text, tbTresc.Text);
        }

    }

    private void chbRepeat_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailHelper zmienna = new MailHelper();
        zmienna.wyslijMaila(tbAdresat.Text, tbTemat.Text, tbTresc.Text);
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MailHelper zmienna = new MailHelper();
        zmienna.wyslijMaila(tbAdresat.Text, tbTemat.Text, tbTresc.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is meant to happen if you click the button a second time while the check box is ticked? Is it going to try to send two lots of email every 5 minutes? Or should it immediately reset the 5 minute timer, but only send one lot of emails?

Comment: You should have your `SendMail` functionality in a separate method. You can then call this method from the `Timer_Tick` event, as well as from the `Button_Click` event. You might consider starting and stopping the timer from the `Checkbox_Changed` event instead of from the button event, but that's up to you.

Comment: One other small suggestion: You might consider making the method `wyslijMaila` as a `static` method, so you don't have to create an instance of the `MailHelper` class each time you want to use it. If you did that, then you can just do a single line: `MailaPomocnik.WyslijMaila(tbAdresat.Text, tbTemat.Text, tbTresc.Text);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to start the timer.

```
this.timer2.Start();
```

However, you can also cleanup your code so it ends up looking like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chbRepeat.Checked)
    {
        this.timer2.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        this.timer2.Stop();
        this.SendMail();
    }
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SendMail();
}

private void SendMail()
{
    MailHelper zmienna = new MailHelper();
    zmienna.wyslijMaila(tbAdresat.Text, tbTemat.Text, tbTresc.Text);
}
```

Comment: Almost exactly what I started writing, except I would suggest starting and stopping the timer in the `Checkbox_Changed` event. But that's my preference, not something the OP stated.

Comment: Thanks, that's exaclty what I needed :) I was trying to use "this" also but couldn't figure out. Sory for newbie questions :) All works fine now. I also cleaned up the code as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start the timer

```
timer2.Start();
```

You can also stop it with

```
timer2.Stop();
```

You can also start and stop the timer through the `Enabled` property.

```
private void chbRepeat_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This automatically starts the timer when you check the check-box and
    // stops it when you un-check the ckeck box.
    timer2.Enabled = chbRepeat.Checked;
}
```

The **[don't repeat yourself (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)** principle says that you shouldn't write the same code more than once. This enhances the maintainability, the testability and readability of your code. You wrote the send mail code 3 times. Extract this code to a new method.

See: [Timer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That's what I did based on answer from CodingYoshi. Thanks anyway, I'm a beginner in .NET/C#.